# Will a Zotac GT 710 2GB DDR3 work with Dell Optiplex 7010 MiniTower

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, low-profile

My Dell Optiplex 7010 has an `i5 2400` and i intend to place an order for a `Zotac GTX 710 2GB` video card. Am not sure if the graphics card is low profile and will work with my PC. My dell Optiplex is the MicroTower version and from what i have read online, the PSU is upgradeable for higher end graphics card, but i just want a graphics card that is plug and play and will fit into the PCIe slot. Before i make an order for this graphics card i just wanna make sure it is what i have described above or does it require some separate connection to the motherboard?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on *precisely* which Optiplex 7010 you have. The card will fit the MT, DT & SFF versions, but not the USFF. See [Dell's tech guide on the models](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/optiplex_7010_technical_guidebook.pdf)

The Zotac is a small card compared to many & in fact is slightly shorter than the optional card supplied for that machine at the time, the AMD HD 7570, whilst similar in other respects.
Aside from a driver install, the card is physically 'plug & play', no additional connections required. It takes power directly from the PCI slot.

Zotac

[image]

AMD

[image]

Comment: Which card is better?

Comment: You need to do your own research on that. We don't do product recommendations here.

Comment: I would also go for active cooling (fan) over passive (heatsink). Also,  https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GeForce-GT-710-vs-AMD-Radeon-HD-7570/m77649vsm9639

Comment: Those Zotacs are fine for what they are - if you want quiet, they fit the bill. Sure, they're a decade old, but they'll run video OK; you wouldn't want to game or do CAD on one though ;)

Comment: Hey this video card is arriving tomorrow, could you confirm for me if it will work 100% with my Dell Optiplex 7010 MiniTower?

Comment: I don't want to check out tomorrow, get to my PC and then realize i bought a hardware that is rejected by the system

Comment: Looks like am gonna have to buy, try and hope it don't make me cry